# Individual Worksheet Passwords

Tags: excel, vba

I've used the 'protection worksheet' option in Excel but in addition, I 'd like to ask the user to input a password upon clicking on each sheet. There's a specific password per sheet. If you don't know the password, I don't want the user to be able to modify anything on the sheet. They can print but can't modify anything.   I have a password per sheet but the code I'm using isn't working...Maybe it's too basic...Can someone please assist?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim Msg As String
    Dim UserEntry As Variant

    Msg = InputBox("What is the password?")

    Do
        Sheet1.Activate
        UserEntry = InputBox(Msg)

            If UserEntry = "test" Then Exit Sub
            If UserEntry = False Then
            Msg = "Invalid Password!"
            Msg = Msg & vbNewLine
            Msg = Msg & "What is the password?"

    Loop
    Sheet1.Activate = UserEntry

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you still require help with this?  Please remember to mark questions as solved by clicking the tick next to the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although it might depend on your version of Excel (I tested in 2007), just right-click the tab and select "**Protect Sheet**". You can set a password for each sheet seperately.

A user will just go to the Review tab in the ribbon and select "**Unprotect sheet**" and enter the password.

You really want to avoid setting passwords via VBA since it's really easy to go into the code to find the password.

Comment: Thanks for replying Issun.  I already protected the individual sheets using the "Protect Sheet" option.  What I don't want is the user to be able to completely unprotect the sheet and accidentally delete any of the formulas.  The workbook is being used by individual departments and everyone is not Excel savvy. I also don't want one department to manipulate the input entered by another department which is why I'd like to protect each worksheet with a password...Security issues.  I appreciate any advice you can lend.

Answer (score 0):

try this in ThisWorkbook module

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        On Error GoTo WrongPassword
            Sh.Unprotect

        CleanUp:

            Exit Sub

        WrongPassword:

            MsgBox "Wrong Password"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sico - I inputted this code in ThisWorkbook module as you suggested but it didn't work.  Do you have any other suggestions? I appreciate any advise you can give.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey Sico - I tried your code again...I forgot to protect the sheet...duhh...Your message printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basics, you can add back the check for an invalid password.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim Msg As String
Dim UserEntry As String

Msg = InputBox("What is the password?")

If Msg = "test" Then

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the password that's entered in the form does not need to be the password to unprotect the sheet.  In my example the tab password is "test" and the unprotect password is "password".

Comment: Hi Jesse - This worked partially...The message and input box appear but the sheet is active no matter what I enter as the password...I also don't want to completely open up the sheet for the user.  I want them to only be able to manipulate the cells I haven't previously locked.  I want to keep the initially security in place (formula hidden and cells locked).  I hope this make sense.  Do you have any other suggestions?  Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: You have to lock the sheet with the "password" manually.  To implement effectively you'd need to add code on workbook save to protect each tab again.

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  I tried a few more things and came up with a slightly different code but your suggestion put me on track.  I was able to develop a code that protects each sheet with different passwords and I used a loop in case you input the wrong password but there are still a few more bugs.